# What is python Sting?

Tags: python, netflix

Sting is referenced in [this blog post by netflix](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/03/python-at-netflix.html) as a RESTful web service tool for reporting on data from hadoop / hive.

> One such application is Sting, a lightweight RESTful web service that slices, dices, and produces visualizations of large in-memory datasets.

I've spent the last 45 minutes trying to find the project online with no luck. There was also a mention of Sting in a [slideshare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/BlakeIrvine/netflix-enabling-a-culture-of-analytics). It is noted on slide 12 and 13 as a reporting tool that is in the same vertical as tableau.

Does anyone know what this project is, where it can be found, or if this is a Netflix closed source / proprietary tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the answer in the comments. There, someone asks:

> lovely wrapup, is Sting a proprietary tool? found no trace in the interwebs whatsoever.

And of the authors replies:

> It's currently internal-only. I don't know what plans there are to OSS it, but there's been significant interest expressed in Sting coming out of this blog post, and the authors of it are aware of that interest :)